# Why does CHIRP report "Frequency not supported"?

Tags: radio-programming, chirp

I have been trying to enter a frequency in CHIRP but every time I do it clears the frequency and issues the message "frequency not supported".

I'm trying to program a Boafeng BF-F8HP with frequency "358.800" but CHIRP refuses to do it. Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome, @jdog, it's nice to have you here.  I'd suggest that you review the [Tour](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) for this stack and review the kinds of questions that are welcome and the research you should do first.  For example, your question is answered by the first hit when searching for the radio model that you listed in the question.  That is the most likely reason your question is receiving downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

That frequency is not within the specified range for this radio, which is documented as 400-520MHz in the UHF band.

Answer (score 0):

(TL;DR: the other answer is correct but doesn't explain why.)

CHIRP works by editing a the raw non-volatile memory in the radio.  This memory is (relatively) expensive, and so the radio is designed to store as much as possible in as little of that memory as possible.

So, typically the radio is designed to store the frequency in the smallest data type possible.  This is typically accomplished by offsetting it from the lowest frequency the radio can receive and only has enough range to cover the highest frequency it can receive.

Because of this, CHIRP has to know the range the radio supports, and is physically unable to store frequencies outside of that range, and gives you an error if you try.